# c linux multithreading networking

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, networking

I have a network application on a gateway. It receives and sends packets. For most of them, my gateway acts as a router, but in some cases, it can receive packets too.

Should I have:

- only one main thread
- a main thread + a dispatch thread in charge of giving it to the correct flow handler
- as many threads as there are flows
- something else.

?

Comment: If you don't want learning Unix network programming (if it isn't your intention and write yourself code) you can use some lib's to help. Look to ENet (http://enet.bespin.org/) . You can read more about it here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/network-programming-enet (from text: This means you don't have to worry about the complexities of forking, preforking, threading or nonblocking calls to connect() and accept() in order to handle multiple connections.)

Answer (score 2):

Doing multithreading correctly is no simple matter, in many cases a [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and [friends](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-the-select-and-poll-methods/1044098) based solution will be a whole lot easier to create.

Comment: `select` and `friends based`? What are those?

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, based on the input from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your case sounds a lot like a typical Unix service daemon. The popular solution to your problem is not to use threads, but forks.

The idea is that your program listens on the socket and waits for connections. As soon as a connection arrives, it forks. The child process then continues to process the connection. The father process itself just continues in the loop and waits for incoming connections.

**Advantages over threading:**

- Very simple program design
- No problems with concurrency
- Established method for Unix/Linux systems

**Disadvantages:**

- Things get complicated when several connections interact with each other (your use case doesn't sound like they would)
- Performance penalty on Windows systems (not on Unix systems!)

You can find many code examples online.

Comment: +1 but forking will be an issue if the different connected partners need to exchange information as the open sockets will live in different processes.

Comment: Yes, I was just adding that to the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about networking applications, but I think it's like this:

- If you have the ability to react asynchronous to the requests you would probably use just one single thread (like in Node.JS). If you won't be able to react asynchronous the main thread would always block the other actions.
- If you are not able to react asynchronous on your requests you have to use more than one thread. But you could achieve that in many different ways: you could create for every request a thread, or a limited number of threads and assign them then to your requests.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is use one main thread and one worker thread per connection. No cap whatsoever. I am assuming that your server will be stateless like a HTTP server.

For stateful servers you will have to figure out some way to control number of threads.